# IOS Issues with sendAsynchronousRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, nsurlconnection

I'm having some serious issue with `[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest: queue: completionHandler:]`.  I am using a rest proxy to log in and authenticate users.  The following I use to log in is shown below:

```
    //Display the progress HUB
    [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Signing Up..." maskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeClear];

    NSError *error;
    [self setUserCredentials];

    //assign the parentView controller to the sender and email to the local class variables
    parentView = sender;
    userEmail = email;

    // create json object for a users session
    NSDictionary* session = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             email, @"email",
                             password, @"password",
                             [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [[UIDevice currentDevice] model], @"device",
                              [[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor].UUIDString, @"device_id",
                              @"APNS", @"push_to",
                              [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"push_id"], @"push_id",
                              nil],
                             @"mession",
                             nil];

    NSData *jsonSession = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:session options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@api/v1/messions.json", CoffeeURL];

    NSLog(@"URL: %@", url);

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:30.0];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [jsonSession length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:jsonSession];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"Length: %d", data.length);

        if (error == nil)
        {
            //if no error ocours set the user defualts and create the mession and log into the app
            NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSDictionary *JSONResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[dataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];

            NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;

            NSLog(@"JSON: %@", JSONResponse);
            NSLog(@"Response: %d", httpResponse.statusCode);

            if (JSONResponse != nil && httpResponse.statusCode == 200)
            {
                [self setUserDefualts:password sessionToUse:JSONResponse deckController:viewDeck sender:sender];
            }

            [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

            //Dismiss progress HUB here and inform user that an internal error has occured
            [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
            NSString *errorString = @"Sorry, an error has occoured while connecting to the Coffee server.";
            UIAlertView *errorAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:errorString delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [errorAlertView show];
        }
    }];
```

When I log in with valid user credentials this code works properly.  When I use invalid credentials the server sends a 401 and a null JSON object to the iOS client.  This should return an `error = nil` and a status code of 401 with a valid non-null response object.  For some reason an error is returned and the response is nil:

```
Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
(NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)" UserInfo=0x1cd53b50 
{NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://192.155.94.183/api/v1/messions.json, 
NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://192.155.94.183/api/v1/messions.json, 
NSUnderlyingError=0x1cdc2b10 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork
 error -1012.)"}
```

This is making it very hard for me to differ between a error that has happened while the request is being sent and a 401 error that is generated by the server when the user's credentials don't match up with the backend.  When I tried creating and handling the request with:

```
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection start];
```

and the NSURLDelegate:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"Called Outside!");

    NSDictionary *jsonSession;
    NSUserDefaults *userInfo = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data", [responseData length]);
    recievedResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSError *err = nil;
    jsonSession = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[recievedResponse dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];

    if ([connection.originalRequest.URL isEqual:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@api/v1/messions.json", CoffeeURL]]])
    {
        NSLog(@"Status: %d", httpResponse.statusCode);
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", jsonSession);
        NSLog(@"Called Inside!");
    }
}
```

The response returned is valid, no error is thrown and the status code is equal to 401 when the user enters invalid credentials.  Why would this work with `(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection` but not with `[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest: queue: completionHandler:]`?

Comment: this has nothing to do with xcode. that is just an editor. instead added objective-c. the programming language is kind of important. please fix your other questions.

Comment: thanks man will make sure not to do that again!

Comment: IMHO, if the server returns a status code of 401, the request shouldn't be considered a failure. As a consequence (according the official documentation) the parameter _error_ MUST be `nil`, and the parameter _data_ MUST NOT be nil. On the other hand, if that method concludes that a request has failed, then the parameter _data_ MUST be `nil` and _error_ MUST NOT be `nil`. However, that would be outright wrong for a status code 401, where the server may send data along with the response, and which then couldn't be obtained by the client because parameter _data_ MUST be `nil`.

Comment: With that said, why is it that the request succeeds when the user credentials are correct?

Comment: This is an example of Apple attempting to insert logic into simple HTTP request handling, abstracting the natural HTTP response in the process, and is imo *very* wrong of them. I completely agree with @CouchDeveloper. Nonsense like this is such a burden on REST developers who just want clean and simple HTTP with obvious results!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a bug in our back-end server.  Sometimes it will send very weird response codes that are handled improperly by the iOS `NSURLConnection` libraries.  In this particular case it showed up as a domain error.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what sort of server-side change allowed `NSURLConnection` to return proper 401 responses?

Answer (score 1):

Don't rely on an error not being generated when the URL handling system receives an error HTTP status code (i.e. not `2xx`).

Instead, use the returned `response` which gives you access to the HTTP status code (check the class at runtime and cast to `NSHTTPURLResponse` so you can access `statusCode`).

Comment: While this might be true, this behavior doesn't make sense. When there is a response from the server, there must be no error. Otherwise, if there is a response and an error, parameter _data_ must be nil, in which case the response data is lost.

Comment: Have you tried with the server returning JSON containing some error message?

Comment: When the server returns the error within the JSON object it still returns a nil response.

Comment: If you need more flexibility than `sendAsynchronousRequest` offers you will need to use the delegate. `sendAsynchronousRequest` is a convenience and this comes with limitations.